# Adjusting text in <div>

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div>
<p style="float: left; width: 28%; margin-right: 2%; background: #efefef; color: green; border: 1px solid #efefef; padding: 10px;">
<strong>Daniel:</strong><br /> 
AGF - SønderjyskE: X (1-1)<br /> 
Liverpool - Arsenal: 2 (2-1)<br /> 
Tottenham - Everton: X (1-0)</p>
</div>
```

What I'll like is the scores to stand right above eachother, like if I made a table. Is this possible somehow? I tried to put in a table inside the `<div>` but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Of course it's possible and instead of putting the table into the div, treat the table as the div itself.

Comment: You need *some* markup separating the scores from the other data. Yes, table will do it. Try again.

Comment: @waxi I'm not quite sure what you mean. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you could do it, with this being one of them...

```css
table,
thead,
tbody,
tr {
  display:block;}
  
th, td {
  text-align:left;
  display:inline-block;}
  
td:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 100px;}

td:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 100px;}
```

```html
 <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Daniel:</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>AGF</td>
          <td>SønderjyskE</td>
          <td>X (1-1)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Liverpool</td>
          <td>Arsenal</td>
          <td>2 (2-1)</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

You can then add any styling you want to further refine the look.